# Separator via DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplateselector

I have a `ToolBar` with a bound `ItemsSource`, I am using `DataTemplateSelector` to determine the `DataTemplate` at runtime (i.e `Button` / `ToggleButton`).

I want to add a `Separator` `DataTemplate`, how do I do that?

Comment: Post the code of your DataTemplateSelector, it will help to answer.

Comment: My question is how to define the template for it ?

Comment: The toolbar control has the `ItemsSource` property, so you can create a collection of clr-objects and add to this collection several dummy objects, with the only one purpose to display a separator. The data template is `<DataTemplate><Separator /></DataTemplate>`. Everything seems to be not difficult, but if I post a sample from scratch, I doubt whether it will help you, so if you can - post xaml code of your toolbar and I will correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ToolBar is an ItemsControl, so it wants to "wrap" the items defined in Items/ItemsSource with a "container". The container is a UIElement that can be used to display the item. In the case of a ListBox for example, the container is a ListBoxItem. If an item is of the proper type, then it can also be it's own container.

This setup allows you to pass a list of strings to a ListBox and have it display property and support selection, keyboard navigation, styling, etc.

In the case of the ToolBar, it really expects it's items to already be a container (i.e. a UIElement). If the item is not a UIElement, then it will wrap it with a ContentPresenter.

Now, the DataTemplateSelecter is used by the container to determine how to display it's item. But you need the item to be a Button, ToggleButton, Separator, etc. You are suggesting that you should add the container in the DataTemplate displayed by the container.

There is also the problem of Styles, which can be seen with this simple example:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Title="Main"
        Height="500" Width="500">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
            <system:String>Test1</system:String>
            <system:String>Test2</system:String>
        </ToolBar>
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button>Test1</Button>
            <Button>Test2</Button>
        </ToolBar>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The buttons in the ToolBar on top will render with the same look as if they were not in the ToolBar. The buttons in the ToolBar on the bottom will get a "toolbar" look. The same goes for Separators.

You can manually apply the Style like so:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Title="Main"
        Height="500" Width="500">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}"
                        Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" /> <!-- Add the Style attribute -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
            <system:String>Test1</system:String>
            <system:String>Test2</system:String>
        </ToolBar>
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button>Test1</Button>
            <Button>Test2</Button>
        </ToolBar>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

You would have the same problem with Separators. So you'd need to manually apply the Style like so:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MySeparatorTemplate">
    <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

You should be able to use the DataTemplate above in your DataTemplateSelector, just like you do with buttons.